# How to drop record if condition matched in Jolt specs

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a use case, where i need to drop a whole set of record if condition satisfied.

**Input**

```json
{
  "Location": "IND",
  "Environment": "",
  "Climate": "Summer",
  "category": "City",
  "status": "De-Active"
}
```

**Condition** : If "status" is equals to "De-Active", the set of record should be dropped or "null"

**Output**

```json
null
```

My specs is working just opposite :)

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "status": {
        "De-Active": {
          "@2": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "status": {
        "De-Active": {
          "*": ""
        },
        "*": {
            "@3": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use such a conditional along with a **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "status": {
        "De-Active": "",
        "*": { "@2": "" } // else case
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demoes*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ are :

[image]

[image]